# Scoped routes creating a routing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to learn to dry up my code a bit but have come across a issue,

Im scoping my routes with controller and path options

```
  scope path: '/administrators', controller: :administrators do
    get 'unverified' => :unverified
    patch 'verify/:id' => :verify
    get 'reported' => :reported
    get 'ban_user' => :ban_user
    patch 'execute_ban/:id' => :execute_ban
  end
```

So this is what ive done so far, all the `get` links are working correctly...
but this is making the `patch 'execute_ban/:id' => :execute_ban` become a extension of `ban user` like this: (also the same with verify)

```
 verified GET      /administrators/unverified(.:format)      administrators#unverifie    
          PATCH    /administrators/verify/:id(.:format)      administrators#verify
 reported GET      /administrators/reported(.:format)        administrators#reported
 ban_user GET      /administrators/ban_user(.:format)        administrators#ban_user
          PATCH    /administrators/execute_ban/:id(.:format) administrators#execute_ban
```

now ive changed my link_to route = `link_to 'ban', ban_user_path(x.id), method: :patch`

but its throwing an routing error saying no path matches.

Is there something im missing, any insight would aooreciated as always.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not go for a more restful design that centers around the resource being modified?

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    get :unverified, on: :collection
    get :reported, on: :collection
    get :ban
    patch :ban, action: 'execute_ban'
  end
end
```

You don't need different paths for the form and acting on a resource - use the  HTTP verb instead.

```
          Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                   Controller#Action
unverified_users GET    /users/unverified(.:format)   users#unverified
  reported_users GET    /users/reported(.:format)     users#reported
        user_ban GET    /users/:user_id/ban(.:format) users#ban
                 PATCH  /users/:user_id/ban(.:format) users#execute_ban
           users GET    /users(.:format)              users#index
                 POST   /users(.:format)              users#create
        new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)          users#new
       edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)     users#edit
            user GET    /users/:id(.:format)          users#show
                 PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)          users#update
                 PUT    /users/:id(.:format)          users#update
                 DELETE /users/:id(.:format)          users#destroy
```

If you are adding a separate controller just for authorization purposes it's an anti-pattern of sorts since you are just adding more complexity for something that should be handled by Pundit/CanCanCan.

Comment: So what your saying is to scrap the administrators controller altogether, merge those actions into the user controller and then use an authorisation gem to control who has access? Sorry im still a newbie to this.

Comment: Also what is on: collection doing?

Comment: Yes pretty much. The default is on: :membrer. on: :collection tells rails to add the routes without an id prefix.

Comment: The key is to not think about it in terms of controllers (which is an implementation detail) and rather focus on the structure of the restful API that your routes create. This creates routes that are very clear in purpose and almost self documenting.